# Error in saving an object: No Hibernate Session bound

Tags: java, multithreading, grails

Error : No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

---

I'm calling thread which will iterate the list and By finding program and channel map it to event object. But I'm not getting that where I'm making mistake? I'm creating thread in loop 100-500

---

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);//creating a pool of 5 threads
Runnable SaveSchedule = new SaveScheduleListThread(scheduleList.clone());
executor.execute(SaveSchedule);
```

---

Following is the Thread Class which implements the Runnable Interface

```
class SaveScheduleListThread implements Runnable
{
    private List<ChannelSchedule> scheduleList;

    public SaveScheduleListThread(List<ChannelSchedule> scheduleList)
    {
//      this.scheduleList = new ArrayList<ChannelSchedule>();
        this.scheduleList=scheduleList;
    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
     */
    public void run()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        log.info "Thread:" +Thread.currentThread().getName() +" Started Time:"+System.currentTimeMillis();
        processScheduleList();
        log.info "Thread:" +Thread.currentThread().getName() +" Ended Time:"+System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

    private void processScheduleList()
    {
        try
        {
            Iterator<ChannelSchedule> scheduleListIterator = scheduleList.iterator();

            ScheduleProgram programDetails = new ScheduleProgram();
            IpgChannel channelDetails = new IpgChannel();
            ChannelSchedule event = new ChannelSchedule(); 

            while(scheduleListIterator.hasNext())
            {
                event = scheduleListIterator.next();

                programDetails = ScheduleProgram.findByTmsId(event.getEventTMSId());
                channelDetails = IpgChannel.findByPrgSvcId(event.getEventPrgSvcId());

                event.setProgram(programDetails);
                event.setChannel(channelDetails);

                event.save();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            session.open()
            log.error "Exception while Processing ScheduleList in Thread"
            log.error e.getStackTrace();
            log.error e.getMessage();

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `processScheduleList()` inside a transaction:

```
Event.withTransaction{
  processScheduleList()
}
```

UPDATE:

flush the session each 500 records:

```
int counter = 0
while(scheduleListIterator.hasNext())
        {
            counter++
            event = scheduleListIterator.next()
            // do stuff
            event.save flush:counter % 500
        }
```

Comment: do you want to mean 
`ChannelSchedule.withTransaction{
            processScheduleList() 
}`

Because Event is not class the class name?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't really matter, what class you use. the static `withTransaction()` is the same for all domain classes. I simply saw a variable named `event` and thought that the class is also called so

Comment: ohhh yes! Its working fine man... Thanks a lot...
Actually here I'm inserting around 700,000 to 800,000 records using multi-threading. Can you please tell me how to optimize this because its taking around 14hrs to finish the task and taking too load on system.

Comment: you have to flush your session each 200-1000 records per thread: `event.save( flush:counter % 200 )`. this would increase performance

Comment: another strategy would be not to use hibernate at all for your batch-processing

Comment: can you please elaborate how am I suppose to use: `event.save( flush:cunter%200 )`  in my code

Comment: I did the same 
`counter++; 
event.save(flush:counter % 1000 );`

but it took 1hr to save 60,000 records... :( which is not feasible in my case because I've to store save more than 700,000 records.

Comment: you have to tweak your setup at several points. one of them would be the threads count. For a 4-core CPU (+ HT) the max thread count should be 8. if you set it to a bigger number, you'll see a slow-down.

Comment: Usign following command: `WMIC CPU Get /Format:List` I found that I've only 2 cores that means I've to use only 4 threads am I right?

Comment: 4 or 2 if no HT available